# JQuery dataTable remove id and class result row need to search in values

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, datatable

I am using DataTable and Search with below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userTable = $('#result').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bInfo": true,
        "oSearch": {"sSearch": ""},
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "scrollX": true,
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
        ]

    });

    $('#user-search').keyup(userTable, function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });

    userTable.fnFilter($(this).val());

    $(".dataTables_filter").hide();
});
```

But my search gives result for id and class also
example if I search 28, it gives result for id=28
or if I search for "green" it gives row with class=green.
In order to remove this id, class, commented code etc what to do ?

Comment: Can you please clarify? It is a little hard to understand what you are asking, mainly in the last paragraph. You talk about removing commented code, but I cannot see anything commented in your code block. Are you trying to remove the element _with_ the id/class, or remove the attribute from the element?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand well your question, but if you want to exclude table columns from the global search you can do that with `{ "bSearchable": false }`, so for example if `id`and `class`columns are the first and second ones, you should do:

```
var userTable = $('#result').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [],
    "bInfo": true,
    "oSearch": {"sSearch": ""},
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "scrollX": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "bSearchable": false },
        { "bSearchable": false },
        null,
        null,
        null,
    ]
});
```

Comment: I want to keep search on table data and not on id or class.
say my one row has <span id=28><input class="red"> KNIGHT</..></..>  and another has <span id=29><input class="green>KING</..></..>. so with my configuration if I search green, it gives row with KNIGHT, but I want to keep search on KNIGHT and KING ( data values only ).